# Disable text input on tap for jQuery-mobile slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Given the default code for a jQuery-mobile slider:

```
<label for="slider-1">Input slider:</label>
<input type="range" name="slider-1" id="slider-1" value="60" min="0" max="100" />
```

the default behavior is that clicking the label field does nothing, but *tapping* the label field brings up a text input on mobile devices.

How can I disable this behavior so that the label displays as plain text on mobile devices?

Comment: I gave you not one, but four different examples below that will all work, and not even an upvote?

Comment: I am very grateful for your reply. However the software does not let me upvote yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should achieve what your trying to do without destroying the attribute of the label tag to it's associated input. I don't have a mobile device handy, so I can't test this to be sure.

```
<label for="slider-1" onclick='return false;'>Input slider:</label>
```

The benefit is it prevents the default behaviour while retaining the accessibility association with the input.

Using jQuery, we can achieve this same thing for all label tags in the document using the preventDefault(); function.

```
$('label').click( function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

or in newer versions of jQuery use the 'on' handler like so...

```
$('label').on('click', false);
```

jQuery mobile **requires** that you have a label paired to the input for the UI to function properly, so removing it is not a solution. However, they do provide for hiding the label through the ui itself

See http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/docs-forms.html

In this example, you are hiding the actual label text, while retaining the label functionality for both jQuery Mobile and accessibility.

```
<label for="slider-1" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Input slider:</label>
Input slider:<input type="range" name="slider-1" id="slider-1" value="60" min="0" max="100" />
```

will hide the actual label 'Input slider:' text while retaining its function. Then you can just add the 'Input slider:' as regular text in front of the input tag which will not invoke anything when clicked on... as it is now only text. I use this approach frequently to regain control of my style formatting options for where the input label is to appear, rather than the very limited formatting options using the actual label tags text.

Also, remember to not fall into one of the biggest mind traps that exist here on SO, and that is that you have to use either jQuery or vanilla javascript, when in reality you can mix it up and use both at the same time, and the folks that bring you the jQuery library encouraged mixed use jQuery and vanilla javascript. Don't be led to believe that you have to use one or the other, and using both is the best approach for more reasons (would require an article to go over all the valid points) than I can shake a stick at.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `label` `for` attribute so when you click it it does not give focus to the input element that has the matching `id` of label for attribute.

```
<label>Input slider:</label>
<input type="range" name="slider-1" id="slider-1" value="60" min="0" max="100" />
```

**[Working demo](http://jsbin.com/ANENaMa/1/edit)**

If you want to remove it after its creation:

You can do this to remove that behavior to all slider `label` elements...

```
$("label.ui-slider").removeAttr("for");
```

or remove for a specific slider `label` using its ID...

```
$("#slider-label").removeAttr("for");
```

Comment: This may work, but at the same time it destroys the accessibility attribute that the <label> tag was invented for. If this is not of concern to you, then you could simply REMOVE the <label> tags and leave it the text. Seeing that this makes the label disfunctional anyway, then there is no reason to have it at all. However, removing attributes designed for accessibilty reasons is considered bad coding practice.

Comment: I was answering taking in account just what OP asked. Telling him to remove a `label` and use a `span` (or whatever) instead does not seem appropriate don't you think?

Comment: That is correct, and that is why I said _'However, removing attributes designed for accessibilty reasons is considered bad coding practice'_ in my reply comment. I sure would not do it this way! Nonetheless, in your example removing the 'for' attribute of the label tag has the same result as removing the label tag altogether.

Comment: did you ever use jQuery mobile? it applies specific styles to `label.ui-slider` so it is normal that users want to use a `label` in the slider widget. I forgot to add `ui-slider` class to `label` in my example and that is why it produces the same result

Comment: I have several popular free apps that use jQuery Mobile, and irregardless of the styles used by the UI, standard  vanilla javascript is still handling events. OP is asking in regard to handling an event, not a style, and that actual event is still handled with vanilla javascript handlers, albeit through the JQuery and jQuery Mobile shorthand methods to invoke the vanilla javascript.

Comment: Also, jQuery Mobile *requires* the label tag be present to function correctly. See my expanded answer above in regard to this.